Using asyncio.run with decorator
I use pyrogram and need to use asyncio.run with decorator; something like:
@app.on_message()
async def reply_on_message(client, message):
    print("Decorator is working")

async def main():
    while True:
        # something change
        sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main())

I've tried to use multithreading and multiprocessing but it doesn't help as well.

instead of time.sleep() can you try asyncio.sleep() ? also your while loop does not have an exit condition which is why it is running endlessly.

For a app.on_message() you need an app first. What should that be?

Your example doesn't show how you imagine to use asyncio.run with a decorator. I don't understand what you mean.

This pattern would work:

The top function is the decorator.
then the decorated async function.


import asyncio

def my_async_decorator(func):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Before calling the async function")
        result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("After calling the async function")
        return result
    return wrapper

@my_async_decorator
async def my_async_function():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Async function executed")

# Call the decorated async function
asyncio.run(my_async_function())

The result would be this:
Before calling the async function
Async function executed
After calling the async function


This decorator could be use to convert asynchronous function to synchronous using asyncio.run:
import asyncio

def to_synchronous(func):
    def synchronous_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.run(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return synchronous_wrapper

Usage example:
@to_synchronous
async def main():
    return 'Hello world'

The main() function is now synchronous and could be used as a target for [project.scripts] in pyproject.toml if needed.
